# how to get group name using User in django

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-orm

I am stuck in django's group module can any one tell me how to solve it.
my problem is now i'm dispalying the username of the logged-in user, i want to display group-name and the profiles present in that group along with the username.and my views are like this,

```
def user(request):
    context = {'user': request.user}
    return render_to_response('username.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

now what do I need to add in order to achieve my requirement

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
        password = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'),
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))
```

username.html is

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.get_username }}. <br/>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

heres my model.py

```
class userprofile(models.Model):
    u_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    u_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    u_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    u_status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    def __str__(self):return self.u_name
```

Comment: If you only need to access to the field "groups". `User.objects.get(id=1).groups.all()`

Comment: @liarez, i need to just display the group name of the user in my username.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User's group list is available as the `user.groups` related manager:

```
def user(request):
    context = {'user': request.user,
               'groups': request.user.groups.all()}
    return render_to_response('username.html', context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

To display this list in the template you have to loop over it:

```
<ul>
{% for group in groups %}
    <li>
        <strong>{{ group.name }}<strong> -
        {% for profile in group.userprofile_set.all %}
            {{ profile.u_name }}{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: request.user.get_username this is what i have used to display username,   for displaying group name can i use request.user.groups

Comment: thank you, but for displaying the profiles in that group how i should modify the views and html

Comment: Where you want to display the group profiles? You can get the list of users in the group using `user_set` related manager: `group.user_set.all()`

Comment: in that same username.html i want to show profiles which are under that group,

Comment: sorry for inconvenience, I have added my models.py also in updated question,,

Comment: its not working,, i am getting the same thing as earlier that is only username and groupname

Comment: This should work.  Are you sure that profiles for these groups are exist?

Comment: my question is like as we assign the users to some group while creating the user, same way while creating the userprofile(my model) also we assign them to particular group(owner in my model)

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
class StuffListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = User
template_name = 'users/stuff_list.html'
context_object_name = 'stuffs'
```

in template
   for loop

```
{% for stuff in stuffs %}
     <tr>
        <td>{{ stuff.username }}</td>

        <td>{{stuff.groups.all.0.name}}</td>
     </tr>

{% endfor %}
```

for single print

```
<a>{{stuff.groups.all.0.name}}</a>
```