# How to display user's role in template

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I made two custom groups from the django's admin page, 'free' and 'premium'. When a user signs up ,their default role is 'free'.

How do i display the group name on a template

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in. your account status is {{  }}</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: A user can belong to two (or more) groups.

Comment: have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28360464/11993840

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your template

```
{{ user.groups.all.0 }}
```